# myHandler.obtainMessage() is not allowed in Service class in android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a service class with a inner class which is a Handler class , unfortunately I am not able to access handler.obtainMessage() in this class .. Can any one give suggestions on this ?

Source code for the Service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private MyHandler myHandler;

    private final class MyHandler extends Handler {
        public MyHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }


        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                // use the unique startId so you don't stop the
                // service while processing other requests
                stopSelfResult(msg.arg1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {

        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {

        }

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Create a new HandlerThread with a specified priority
        HandlerThread thread = new  HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread",Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        // Start the handler thread so that our Handler queue will start
        // processing messages
        thread.start();
        // Run the handler using the new HandlerThread
        myHandler = new MyHandler(thread.getLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't?  There's no problem with doing that.  If you're getting an error, post that.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the wrong `Handler` class imported. It should be `android.os.Handler`, not `java.util.logging.Handler`.