# Handler can't instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-handler

What happened to Handler class. Why it is showing to me this type of error? I can solve it by calling Handler override methods. But I don't want them. What should I do.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    blink();

}

private void blink(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); //showing error and need to call their override methods. 
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int timeToBlink = 1000;    //in milissegunds
            try{Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);}catch (Exception e) {}
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blink);
                    if(txt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                        txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    blink();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

}
```

[image: this is the error is showing]

even when I call the Handler methods, the error is still exist.

```
 @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {

    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Handler is an abstract class, you are meant to implement the methods for that class.

Comment: You've got the wrong `Handler` class imported. It should be `android.os.Handler`, not `java.util.logging.Handler`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215126

Comment: My bad! Sorry, did not notice the other bit of code there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are importing the wrong Handler, you want to use android.os.Handler not java.util.logging.Handler.